# Incomplete type C++

Tags: c++, circular-reference

I get the following error when I try to execute this code segment : "Menu does not name a type".I know its something to do with the circular references, but for the life of me I can't figure out what. Also, menu, go, and manager are repeatedly giving errors. The code segments are posted below :

```
#ifndef GO__H
#define GO__H

#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout; using std::endl; 
using std::string;

#include "ioManager.h"
#include "gui.h"
#include "clock.h"
#include "menu.h"

//class Menu;
class Go {
public:
    Go ();
    void play();
private:
    SDL_Surface *screen;
    Gui gui;
    Menu menu;

    void drawBackground() const;
    Go(const Go&);
    Go& operator=(const Go&);
};

#endif
```

Here's Menu :

```
#ifndef MENU_H
#define MENU_H

#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "ioManager.h" 
#include "gui.h"
#include "clock.h"
#include "manager.h"

class Menu {
public:
    Menu ();
    void play();

private:
    const Clock& clock;
    bool env;

    SDL_Surface *screen;
    Gui gui;
    Manager mng;

    void drawBackground() const;
    Menu(const Menu&);
    Menu& operator=(const Menu&);
};

#endif
```

Manager :

```
#ifndef MANAG_H
#define MANAG_H

#include "go.h"
class Manager { 
  Go go;
  //other code
}
```

Can you see where the problem is? Error message:

> In file included from go.h:13:0,
>   from manager.h:33,
>    from manager.cpp:2:
>     menu.h:28:11: error: field ‘mng’ has incomplete type

Comment: On the surface that looks OK, are you sure that is the code that is giving you the error?

Comment: actually im getting another similiar error now, will post code!

Comment: Could menu.h be somehow referencing go.h?  This can cause that kind of error.

Comment: Try to reduce the code to the minimum number of lines that generate the errors - i.e. remove all members other than `Menu` and everything that is relevant, all unneeded includes, and edit the question.

Comment: Try changing `Menu menu;` to `Menu* menu;` inside `class GO`

Comment: Try adding a #error directive inside your menu.h just before the class Menu to make sure it is actually being included.  You may be #define MENU_H in another include file.

Comment: You might also consider formatting your code a little better.  It's a bit painful to read as is.

Comment: Also, what line number from which file does your compiler report the error with Menu.  That would be very helpful

Comment: Please include **complete** compiler messages, with line numbers and file names. Also consider including line numbers in code listings, if they are longer than a couple dozen lines. It's no fun to reconstruct this information from hints and fragments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`manager.h` includes `go.h` which includes `menu.h` which includes `manager.h` ...

The `class Menu` is being defined before it ever gets to the definition of `class Manager`.

However, `class Menu` needs a `Manager` but since the compiler doesn't know about `Manager` yet it doesn't know how big to make it.

You could forward declare `class Manager` and make the `mng` member of `Menu` a pointer or reference:

```
class Manager;

class Menu {
    ...
    Manager* mng;

    // or this:
    //Manager& mng; 
    ...
```

[Here's a good explanation of circular references and how to fix them.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/628079/416627)

Comment: Do I get rid of this by removing #include menu.h from go.h? - But each of those classes needs an object from the included class.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are missing the semicolon at the end of the declaration of your `Manager` class in manger.h.

You are also missing the `#endif` to close your include guard.

Comment: Oh yes, didn't spot that, that's an issue too.

Comment: Assuming that is the full source file.

Comment: No, those are in the real file.